# Remove duplicate values in string for all values in a column of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like df below.

```
c1 <- c(4, 3, 6, 5, 2)
c2 <- c("AAA, AAA, VAA, LLA", "CEA, CEA, HEA, CKA, NEA, TEA", "RFA, LIA, VIA, CIA, CIA, RKA", "JHD, JKE, JKE, HGH", "JII, JII, ISA, KSA")
df <- data.frame(c1, c2)
```

I want to get rid of any duplicates for the values in the second column. So for example, it should remove one of the "AAA" in the second column for the value corresponding to "4" (first row). How can this be done for all cells in the second column?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably `vapply(strsplit(as.character(df$c2), ", "), function(x) toString(unique(x)), "")`

Answer (score 2):

**Updated solution**

As [@RichScriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/rich-scriven) rightly pointed out in the comments, the original `c2` is a factor column.

```r
levels(df$c2)
#> [1] "AAA, AAA, VAA, LLA"           "CEA, CEA, HEA, CKA, NEA, TEA"
#> [3] "JHD, JKE, JKE, HGH"           "JII, JII, ISA, KSA"          
#> [5] "RFA, LIA, VIA, CIA, CIA, RKA"
```

To update the factor levels we could do something like:

```r
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

levels(df$c2) <- map_chr(str_split(levels(df$c2), boundary("word")),
                         function(x) paste0(unique(x), collapse = ", "))
```

Which gives us:

```r
levels(df$c2)

#> [1] "AAA, VAA, LLA"           "CEA, HEA, CKA, NEA, TEA"
#> [3] "JHD, JKE, HGH"           "JII, ISA, KSA"          
#> [5] "RFA, LIA, VIA, CIA, RKA"

df
#>   c1                      c2
#> 1  4           AAA, VAA, LLA
#> 2  3 CEA, HEA, CKA, NEA, TEA
#> 3  6 RFA, LIA, VIA, CIA, RKA
#> 4  5           JHD, JKE, HGH
#> 5  2           JII, ISA, KSA
```

**Original solution (which adds a new list column rather than updating factor levels)**

For a `tidyverse` approach you could do something like this to put the results in a new column `c3`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

mutate(df, c3 = map(str_split(c2, boundary("word")), unique))
#>   c1                           c2                      c3
#> 1  4           AAA, AAA, VAA, LLA           AAA, VAA, LLA
#> 2  3 CEA, CEA, HEA, CKA, NEA, TEA CEA, HEA, CKA, NEA, TEA
#> 3  6 RFA, LIA, VIA, CIA, CIA, RKA RFA, LIA, VIA, CIA, RKA
#> 4  5           JHD, JKE, JKE, HGH           JHD, JKE, HGH
#> 5  2           JII, JII, ISA, KSA           JII, ISA, KSA
```

And I'm fairly certain there'll also be a nice way to do this in base R that someone else can provide.